# how can I run maven test case

Tags: maven, automated-tests

I have create a small web project using maven.so I want to add test classes and directory to that project.I'm using eclipse as IDE my source folder is "src/main/java" I added test source folder "src/test/java" and added one test class with one test selenium casetry to compile and run it using "mvn test" command,But console only shows "run 0 failure 0 error 0  skip 0",Can any one explain me how to run my testcases properly,is there any configurations to do ?
thnxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn test` runs unit tests without additional configuration, but for selenium you need to refer to [selenium maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/selenium-maven-plugin/).

If your tests are not in the default location `src/test/java`, you can specify the alternate location as follows:

```
<testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/my/alternate/location</testSourceDirectory>
```

Comment: yaa I know that I added that one also.In my project there is no test package so how can I add test package manually to maven.I want to run that test.

Comment: @123Ex maven runs all tests in src/test/java - so not sure you mean by test package.

Comment: It is like this I have create a simple maven project,But that did not contain "src/test/java" what I have done is I create a that folder manually using my eclipse IDE,then I tried "mvn test" but that did not compile my test classes and does not show test class in out put test folder so how can I correct this ??thnxx for the reply!!

Comment: Well, that should be ok. Is your folder structure correct - does src have two sub-folders - main and test?  Does mvn test run fine outside Eclipse?

Comment: that is the problem I think my folder structure is not correct,mvn test runs fine but that does not show any test,so how can I integrate my  test cases to this??can you explain me?

Comment: @123Ex. I thought you solved the problem.  Assuming you have an alternate folder structure for tests, I have updated the answer suitably.

Comment: Thank you verry much your support!!